# Relation between roots of three quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2 \alpha$  is a root of $ax^2 + bx +c = 0$ , $ \beta$  is a root of $ax^2 - 2bx - c = 0$ ,and real number $ a(> 0) , b , c $ are such that $ \beta < \alpha $ , then a root $\gamma $ of $ax^2 +4 bx +2c = 0$  satisfies

1 ) $ \alpha <\gamma < 2\beta $

2) $  \beta <\gamma < \alpha $

3) $   \gamma < \beta < \alpha $

4) $\beta < \alpha< \gamma  $

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/let-a-b-c-be-real-numbers-a-0-if-alpha-is-a-zero-of-a2-x2-bx-c0-beta-is-the-zero-of-a2x2-bx-c0-and-0-29540

Comment: I could not understand why people have downvoted? I am really not having any idea to proceed. That's why I did not mention my attempt..

Answer (score 0):

These are the parabolas concave up so using some drawings you can reach a conclusion which is not so much time consuming, but for the algebraic approach you can simply calculate the roots from discriminant and using the inequality \begin{equation}
\beta<\alpha \end{equation} you can reach a conclusion.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?@Butane

Comment: These equations' roots can be found out by quadratic formula (the one that uses discriminant) then elaborating through the outcomes, means the roots will have certain inequality relation can be understood from the Alfa>Beta relation that is given in the question. Basically just find the roots in terms of the coefficients of quadratic equations then compare them using the given informations.